# JS smooth scroll not working with append anchor

Tags: jquery, append, smooth-scrolling

I've created [this pen](https://codepen.io/dragoeco/pen/XWjgVEB) to show exactelly my problem but in short, I can't make a jQuery append anchor to work smoothly (with [css-tricks](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/jquery/smooth-scrolling/) snippet), when all HTML anchor work perfectly.

As you can see, the "JS button" jumps directly to the bottom of page, but the "HTML button" and "Back to top" do this smoothly.

I don't understand where the problem is. I searched for more than an hour without success so here I am :p

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

    $(function() {  
        $('a[href*="#"]')
            .not('[href="#"]')
            .not('[href="#0"]')
            .click(function(event) {
                if (location.pathname.replace(/^\//, '') == this.pathname.replace(/^\//, '') && location.hostname == this.hostname) {
                    var target = $(this.hash);
                    target = target.length ? target : $('[name=' + this.hash.slice(1) + ']');
                    if (target.length) {
                        event.preventDefault();
                        $('html, body').animate({
                            scrollTop: target.offset().top
                        }, 1000, function() {
                        var $target = $(target);
                        $target.focus();
                        if ($target.is(":focus")) {
                            return false;
                        } else {
                            $target.attr('tabindex','-1');
                            $target.focus();
                        };
                    });
                }
            }
        });
    });
  // My anchor
  $(function () {
            $('#link').append('<a href="#bottom">JS button</a>');
    });
  
  });
```

```css
* {
  font-weight: bold;
}
span {
  display: block;
  margin: 20px 0;
}
a {
    color: dodgerblue;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 8px 20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="link"><a href="#bottom">HTML button</a></div>
<div><span>1</span><span>2</span><span>3</span><span>4</span><span>5</span><span>6</span><span>7</span><span>8</span><span>9</span><span>10</span><span>11</span><span>12</span><span>13</span><span>14</span><span>15</span><span>16</span><span>17</span><span>18</span><span>19</span><span>20</span><span>21</span><span>22</span><span>23</span><span>24</span><span>25</span><span>26</span><span>27</span><span>28</span><span>29</span><span>30</span><span>31</span><span>32</span><span>33</span><span>34</span><span>35</span><span>36</span><span>37</span><span>38</span><span>39</span><span>40</span><span>41</span><span>42</span><span>43</span><span>44</span><span>45</span><span>46</span><span>47</span><span>48</span><span>49</span><span>50</span></div>
<div><a href="#link" id="bottom">Back to top</a></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just move the link embed code above the fade code. Like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $(function () {
     $('#link').append('<a href="#bottom">JS button</a>');
   });
   ...
});
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

$(function () {
  $('#link').append('<a href="#bottom">JS button</a>');
});

    $(function() {  
        $('a[href*="#"]')
            .not('[href="#"]')
            .not('[href="#0"]')
            .click(function(event) {
                if (location.pathname.replace(/^\//, '') == this.pathname.replace(/^\//, '') && location.hostname == this.hostname) {
                    var target = $(this.hash);
                    target = target.length ? target : $('[name=' + this.hash.slice(1) + ']');
                    if (target.length) {
                        event.preventDefault();
                        $('html, body').animate({
                            scrollTop: target.offset().top
                        }, 1000, function() {
                        var $target = $(target);
                        $target.focus();
                        if ($target.is(":focus")) {
                            return false;
                        } else {
                            $target.attr('tabindex','-1');
                            $target.focus();
                        };
                    });
                }
            }
        });
    }); 
  });
```

```css
* {
  font-weight: bold;
}
span {
  display: block;
  margin: 20px 0;
}
a {
    color: dodgerblue;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 8px 20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="link"><a href="#bottom">HTML button</a></div>
<div><span>1</span><span>2</span><span>3</span><span>4</span><span>5</span><span>6</span><span>7</span><span>8</span><span>9</span><span>10</span><span>11</span><span>12</span><span>13</span><span>14</span><span>15</span><span>16</span><span>17</span><span>18</span><span>19</span><span>20</span><span>21</span><span>22</span><span>23</span><span>24</span><span>25</span><span>26</span><span>27</span><span>28</span><span>29</span><span>30</span><span>31</span><span>32</span><span>33</span><span>34</span><span>35</span><span>36</span><span>37</span><span>38</span><span>39</span><span>40</span><span>41</span><span>42</span><span>43</span><span>44</span><span>45</span><span>46</span><span>47</span><span>48</span><span>49</span><span>50</span></div>
<div><a href="#link" id="bottom">Back to top</a></div>
```

Comment: Damn! I was sure it will not work if I move it like that... I was wrong and should have test this :p  I'm not sure to understand why it's working with the embed code above but not bellow, but it works now so thanks a lot Sergey.

Comment: @dragoeco, because a block with a smooth transition logic does not detect your `append()`, if this block is after a smooth transition, inside `$(document).ready(function() { ... }`. I was glad to help, friend :)